# Bonferroni correction vs Adjusted Bonferroni p value

Tags: bonferroni

In R, we can use the following options for POST HOC, with Bonferroni P value

```
summary(glht(fit, linfct=mcp(variable="Tukey")),test=adjusted("Bonferroni"))
```

Based on my understanding the Bonferroni correction is alpha divided by the number of comparisons. It means we can use

```
summary(glht(fit, linfct=mcp(variable="Tukey")),test=adjusted("none"))
```

and compare the nonadjusted p value with alpha/number of test.

Now I was wondering how the first function adjusts the values as for correction we have to divide the alpha to the number of the test? Also are the two ways of analysis provide the same result?

Comment: I think an appropriate answer would be the Bonferroni adjusted p-value equals 1 - (1 - p) ^ n_tests. It is as it is since **alpha divided by the number of comparisons** is just an approximation of the Bernoulli trials.

Comment: @AlexeyBurnakov That's Šidák adjustment

Comment: Isn't it the same procedure as the Bonferroni one?

Comment: @AlexeyBurnakov It's not. Bonferroni procedure is the approximation you mentioned, which results in $p_\text{ADJ}= n \cdot p$

Comment: @Firebug, thank you, I have read about it. They are VERY close and differ in only that Bonferroni is usually approximated as n*p or alpha/n. Interesting information, thanks.